# Reverse order of Thunderbird new message notification

Tags: email, thunderbird

Is there a way to reverse the order of Thunderbird new message notifications?

Say I have 3 unread emails (I've seen the subject, they are not important so I ignore them).  Now when a new email comes in, the notification will show these 3 and not the new one.

Is there a way to show the newest emails first?

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct solution, but a workaround: I use the following Autohotkey script to remove the "new" status whenever I tab away from the Thunderbird window. This way "I've seen the subject" means that the new indicator is gone (just unread now). When new mail comes in, then it is shown alone.

How it works: When the Thunderbird window becomes "NotActive" then the shortcut {F5} is send to the Window, which triggers "Get New Messages for Current Account", which in turn resets the "new" status.

```
#
# Thunderbird Reset New on Inactive
#
SetTitleMatchMode RegEx

#Persistent 
SetTimer, MsgBoxCheck, 500

MsgBoxCheck:
{
  IfWinActive, Mozilla Thunderbird
  {
    WinWaitNotActive, Mozilla Thunderbird
    ControlSend, , {F5}, Mozilla Thunderbird
  }

  SetTimer, MsgBoxCheck, 500
}
```